# по какой причине происходит вызов второго события?

Tags: javascript, события

```js
function listner(e) {
 console.log("header");
 document.addEventListener("click", function f() {
  console.log("document");
 });
}

document.getElementsByTagName("header")[0].addEventListener("click", listner);
```

```css
.header {
  height: 200px;
  background: #142;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>html-ready</title>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
</head>
<body class="page">
 <header class="header">
 </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод [`.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) может принимать параметр `useCapture`. По умолчанию этот параметр равен `false`, следовательно обработчики будут срабатывать во время фазы всплытия события.

Во время этой фазы, событие всплывает от целевого элемента, к контейнеру верхнего уровня, которым является `document`.

Если вернуться к коду:

в момент обработки события на целевом элементе обработчик добавляется к контейнеру, так как параметр `useCapture` не указан обработчик добавляется к фазе всплытия, которая как раз и идет, поэтому после выполнения обработчика на целевом элементе и всплытия по контейнерам, выполняется свежедобавленный обработчик на document.

Можно добавлять внутренний обработчик на фазу захвата, в этом случае он будет выполнен только для следующего клика:

```js
function listner(e) {
  console.log("header");
  document.addEventListener("click", function f(e) {
    console.log("document");
    e.stopPropagation();
  }, true);
}

document.getElementsByTagName("header")[0].addEventListener("click", listner);
```

```css
.header {
  height: 200px;
  background: #142;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
</header>
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе большое. Как всегда на высоте.

Answer (score 2):

По причине добавления обработчика события `click` внутри обработчика события `click` и всплытия события `click`.

Пощелкайте мышкой несколько раз, и Вы увидите, что количество обработчиков, выводящих "document", увеличивается.

Comment: По поводу того, что с каждым разом все больше обработчиков добавляются  к `document` это я знаю, но суть в другом. Не понимаю, почему происходит вызов обработчика события у `document`, ибо я его присвоил, а не вызвал. Если обратите внимание, то при первом клике, сразу вызываются два события.

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный Потому что событие поднимается (всплывает) от `header`-а (дочернего элемента) к документу (родителю), и Вы успеваете зарегистрировать обработчик то того, как событие дойдет до документа.